# CSS: Image border wider than image, though height is correct

Tags: html, css, image

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

  div.img1 {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-color: #384b5d;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img1">
  <img src="http://www.hotelseaviewdiu.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Business-Meeting.jpg" width=50% height=50%>
</div>
</body>
```

The problem that is occurring, is that the border around my image is wider, maybe by 50px on each side, whereas the height of the border rests just fine on the image. I am new to CSS, and not really sure why this is happening.

This is all within google site's HTML box as well.

I adjusted the width and height to create a smaller image with an adjusted ratio. When I eliminate these ratio %'s, the border fits perfectly, both height and width, so I assume the problem is somewhere within my image adjustment within the

```
<img src>
```

tag.

Thank for any and all help. I really appreciate it.

Regards,

Comment: please provide an example by inserting a snipper or use https://jsfiddle.net/ or any other ;-)

Comment: That's because you are targeting the div that the image is in rather than the img. Apply the border properties to `div.img1 img` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the border to `div.img1 img` instead and keep the `text-align` property of the div:

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/NGKWyE

Comment: Never had a chance to follow up and thank you for your help and time!